# iPhone SE locked and unable to unlock

Tags: password, iphone

I forgot the pass code of my iPhone SE.
I have switched it off now.
Yesterday, I reset my pass code but now I can't remember it.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8 and later, the only way to unlock the code is restoring from iTunes. Hope you already backed up your phone.

One more trick, ask your family member to see whether they knew the code. I once luckily got it back from my wife.

Answer (score 0):

You may use iTunes to reset your iPhone SE to factory default or restore it from a backup (iCloud / Computer file) while the iPhone is in recovery mode.
There are already tutorials specifically outlining every step of this process, hence I won't post them here.

This is just one of the houndred plus available on YouTube: [Video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL3wIFzqyao)

At this moment I am unsure if this answers your question or not, as I can't quite make out the actual question. Please revise and ask correctly.